# Cannot add property 0, object is not extensible

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

Whenever I try to push an object in to array using post method It shows this warning

This is happening in React-Native with redux and I am using firebase in backend.

```
Exception was thrown by user callback. TypeError: Cannot add property 0, object is not extensible
at Array.push (<anonymous>)
at blob:file:///d0f11e65-c690-4662-8ef6-91001f662c11:104234:59
at blob:file:///d0f11e65-c690-4662-8ef6-91001f662c11:90326:24
at LLRBNode.inorderTraversal (blob:file:///d0f11e65-c690-4662-8ef6-91001f662c11:89149:58)
at SortedMap.inorderTraversal (blob:file:///d0f11e65-c690-4662-8ef6-91001f662c11:89453:31)
at ChildrenNode.forEachChild (blob:file:///d0f11e65-c690-4662-8ef6-91001f662c11:89926:39)
at DataSnapshot.forEach (blob:file:///d0f11e65-c690-4662-8ef6-91001f662c11:90325:35)
at blob:file:///d0f11e65-c690-4662-8ef6-91001f662c11:104233:35
at onceCallback (blob:file:///d0f11e65-c690-4662-8ef6-91001f662c11:90716:55)
at blob:file:///d0f11e65-c690-4662-8ef6-91001f662c11:90450:26
```

Error is

```
ExceptionsManager.js:63 Cannot add property 0, object is not extensible
```

Code

```
authLoggedInUserKey = userKey;
                let requestedUser = [];
                //This code get data form the user to whom loggedin user send request
                let userDetail = userRef.child(authLoggedInUserKey).child('requestedUserData');
                userDetail.once('value',(snap) =>{
                    snap.forEach((child) => {
                        let requestedUserKey = child.val().requestedUser;
                        let requestedUserDetail = userRef.orderByKey().equalTo(requestedUserKey);
                        requestedUserDetail.once('value',(snap1)=>{
                            snap1.forEach((child1) => {

                                requestedUser.push({ //Error generated here
                                    firstName: child1.val().firstName,

                                })

                            })

                        })
                    })
```

Comment: suffering from the same problem in Angular application. I hope you have the answer by now

Comment: yeah I was working on react at that time and my array got refresh or reload every time when I trying to use that. That's why this issue generated. In react there is concept of using storage for state and props and I was not using that. That's another reason. When I started using storage this issue sorted out. So what I can say that please check you array or object before using that. It may possible that you are trying to use undefine object or something. Hope it will help you. Thanks :)